# com.apple.main-thread EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS (at NSTimer from iOS 8.x)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer, nsnotificationcenter, crashlytics

Got a crash from crashlytics.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread

0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x197e37bdc objc_msgSend + 28
1  Foundation                     0x1881192c8 -[NSCFTimer initWithFireDate:interval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:] + 140
2  Foundation                     0x188123d3c +[NSTimer(NSTimer) scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:] + 140
3  RV PetSafety                   0x1000fd2a0 -[HomeViewController UIApplicationDidBecomeActive:] (HomeViewController.m:179)
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1872dc1e0 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
5  CoreFoundation                 0x18721b370 _CFXNotificationPost + 2060
6  Foundation                     0x188116cc0 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 72
7  UIKit                          0x18bb664c0 -[UIApplication _stopDeactivatingForReason:] + 464
8  UIKit                          0x18bd77818 -[UIApplication _handleNonLaunchSpecificActions:forScene:withTransitionContext:] + 2664
9  FrontBoardServices             0x18f56d640 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 28
10 CoreFoundation                 0x1872ee124 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 20
11 CoreFoundation                 0x1872ed22c __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 312
12 CoreFoundation                 0x1872eb850 __CFRunLoopRun + 1756
13 CoreFoundation                 0x1872191f4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
14 GraphicsServices               0x1903835a4 GSEventRunModal + 168
15 UIKit                          0x18bb4a784 UIApplicationMain + 1488
16 RV PetSafety                   0x1001161e8 main (main.m:14)
17 libdyld.dylib                  0x198492a08 start + 4
```

Where my code:

```
- (void)UIApplicationDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if([updateTimer isValid]) {
        [updateTimer invalidate];
    }
    updateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:refreshInterval
                                                   target:self
                                                 selector:@selector(refreshData)
                                                 userInfo:nil
                                                  repeats:YES];
}
```

Whenever my app becomes active I want to update my `NSTimer` time. I need to call API period of time. I got a crash on this method. On above selector method `refreshData` having API call. Initializing `NSNotificationCenter` at `viewWillAppear`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(UIApplicationDidBecomeActive:)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```

Crashlytics title `HomeViewController.m line 179 -[HomeViewController UIApplicationDidBecomeActive:]` on that line

```
updateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:refreshInterval
                                                   target:self
                                                 selector:@selector(refreshData)
                                                 userInfo:nil
                                                  repeats:YES];
```

I didn't seen any `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];` in this project. Just now I add that but, I want to confirm is crash occur because of multiple `addObserver` or in `NSTimer` initializing?

**Update 16/08/2017:**

Got this error couple of time and both same iOS version 8.x

> iOS version: 8.4.1 (12H321)
>
> Model: iPhone 5c (Model A1456, A1532)

**Update 17/08/2017:**

1st crash occurred more than 3 months ago and 2nd one occurred more than 2 weeks. I can't get crash details in `Xcode-organizer` crash tab. I have seen some other crash only in `Crashlytics`, not in `Xcode-organizer`. I can't understand `Crashlytics` crash details compare to `Xcode-organizer`

Comment: Where you added this BecomeActive obeserver ?

Comment: at `HomeViewController` `viewWillAppear` mentioned in the question above observer init code.

Comment: is there any other viewController in your app or you just at Home ViewController and getting this crash ?

Comment: Just `HomeViewController` only for `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`. I have some other view controller with custom `observer`, till now I didn't get any crash from other view controllers.

Comment: @CodeChanger Check today update in question: Is that because of `Crashlytics` work hard to get every `crash`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't put the observer code at viewWillAppear because of the code will call mutilate times:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(UIApplicationDidBecomeActive:)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                           object:nil];
```